# Why doesn't this NSPredicate work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, predicate, nspredicate

I have a very simple NSPredicate as such:

```
NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name beginswith '%@'", theString];
[matchingTags filterUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
```

This causes the array to have 0 results when theString == "p"

However, when I do this:

```
NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name beginswith 'p'"];
[matchingTags filterUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
```

I get over 100 results, as expected.

I have checked "theString" with NSLog() and its value is correct. I feel like I am missing some crucial secret. Possibly because I am using a string and not a character?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-208600)

> If you use variable substitution using
>   %@ (such as firstName like %@), the
>   quotation marks are added for you
>   automatically.

So basically, it's looking for names that start with "p", instead of p. Changing your code to:

```
NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name beginswith %@", theString];
```

should work

Comment: Damn I thought I had tried that already. But yes, that was it. Thanks!